# WinForms control takes too long to load

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

In a WPF application I have a user control that hosts a win forms RichTextBox control using the WindowsFormsHost. The user control is used in a panel that is made visible at a certain time. The problem is that the forms control is displayed a few moments before the containing panel. I tried delaying the display of the RTB until the panel is shown, but then the UI freezes for 2-4 seconds when the forms control is loaded. Please help if you know a solution to make the control load faster. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code where it is (you think ) going wrong, or sleeping?

Comment: I suppressed any processing for the RTB and I don't do much in the parent panel either. So the actual loading of the control seems to be the problem. If setting the Visibility to Collapsed for the RTB the panel is displayed instantly. When changing the RTB Visibility (from Snoop) to Visible I see the same freezing of the UI until the control is loaded.

Comment: you should not use any sleep to delay the display, instead use available events such as Loaded, Active, Focus, etc. Sleep in main thread is a bad move.

Comment: yes Hosting is expensive even Hosting WpfControl in Winforms using System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost takes more time. i hope nothing will be wrong in your code, WindowsFormsHost itself will take more time to add child control into it

Comment: can you show the code you add the delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution for this :) Actually, the WindowsFormsHost had a Transparent background set, and just removing the transparency solved the performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a profiler to see where most of the time is consumed, have a look here: [What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)

Comment: While this is certainly helpful advice, it is not an answer.