# Show and resize objects faster in WinForms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, object

I'm making a game in c# and I'm using Panels as buttons since they can be semi transparent and they're easy to paint text on and resize. The problem is when I want to show these buttons on screen they take about half a second to load and paint text on. The problem ISN'T that it's flickering, I already have double buffering on, it's that you can visibly see it loading and it just looks very unfinished. This is even worse when they've already been loaded and I go full screen and they change size to adjust; it takes at least a solid second. My question is basically: how do I get objects to load and resize faster?

Comment: GDI and GDI+ are not known for being fast.  You should look at MonoGame, it's still c# and made for making games.

Answer (score 0):

I will start off by saying: *Yes, GDI+ (Which is used in WinForms is **NOT** the fastest out there.* Keeping that in mind, i managed to create multiple games using it without any external libraries.

### What it comes down to?

If the project is not too heavy loaded with controls, a well programmed project should run smoothly.

I would try this approach:

- Don't load unnecessary controls if **they are unneeded**, on `Form_Load` preferably, don't load any controls on `Form_Load`.

Creating and populating controls takes lot of time, so if you can, delay it or do it on demand

Call an external function at the end of `Form_Load` for better esthetics and **maybe** some performance.

For example, you can avoid creating controls on all pages of Tab Control right away and do so in either `Appllication.Idle` event or when that tab is selected from `SelectedTabChanged` event.

- By looking at other questions, similar to this one i could see that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611566/winforms-control-takes-too-long-to-load). Please take a brief look at it and check if the solution fits your problem.

*Used articles: [12 Tips To Speed-up Your Windows Forms Applications](https://devcomponents.com/blog/?p=361) - Take a look at it!*

Good luck.